# absolute positioning of tikzpicture in memoir

Tags: tikz-pgf

I need to position some graphic using some graphic material in the
upper left corner of the stock (page is smaller). Consider the following
example:

```
\documentclass[a3paper,showtrims]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pageaiv
\isopage
\setpagecc{\paperheight}{\paperwidth}{*}
\checkandfixthelayout
\begin{document}
\chapter{A}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\node [xshift=1cm,yshift=1cm] at (current page.north west)
      [text width=7cm,fill=red!20,rounded corners,above right]
{
  This is an absolutely positioned text in the
  upper left corner.
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This example gets positioned at a strange place. 
How can I place the tikzpicture 1cm from the top left corner of
the stock, i.e. the a3paper, and not the page (a4paper)?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Googling "memoir tikz stock" yields http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/modifying-current-page-node/